# Error while sorting JSON array using flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I have implemented a code to sort the JSON returned after hitting a particular URL, but getting the following error:

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'value'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:11
Tried calling: value)
```

This is the code i implemented:

```
Future<Semdata> semdata(String url, {Map body} ) {
    return http.post(url,
          body:body).then((http.Response response){
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    
    var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
    List unitdata = extractdata["unit"];
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(response.body);
    unitdata.sort((a,b){
        return a.value["unit_no"].toString().compareTo(b.value["unit_no"].toString());
      });

    print(unitdata);
    return Semdata.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    
    });
          
  }
```

I want to sort the JSON with respect to **univ_spec_sub_id** and **unit_no.** . For example all the **unit_no.** sorted in numerical order **under univ_spec_sub_id** as 53
This is the JSON :

```
"unit": [
        {
            "unit_id": "268",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "13",
            "unit_name": "File Handling and Dictionaries",
            "unit_no": "6",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "274",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "24",
            "unit_name": "Object Oriented Programming",
            "unit_no": "5",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "300",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "14",
            "unit_name": "Decision Control Statements",
            "unit_no": "2",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "304",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "29",
            "unit_name": "Problem Solving, Programming and Python Programming",
            "unit_no": "1",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "392",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "11",
            "unit_name": "Functions & Modules",
            "unit_no": "3",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "393",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "28",
            "unit_name": "Strings",
            "unit_no": "4",
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "298",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "59",
            "no_chapters": "16",
            "unit_name": "Electromagnetism",
            "unit_no": "1",
        },
]
```

Comment: The json you posted is not valid.

Comment: Just for clarification: you want to sort first after "univ_spec_sub_id" und if they are equal you want to sort after "unit_no"?

Comment: I couldn't add the entire JSON so its just a snippet. It returns more values with differrent uni_spec_sub_id. And yes if univ_spec_sub_id are same i want to sort w.r.t unit_no

Comment: OK, then have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and pasted it in a dart test (and fixed the invalid json). Please have a look at the test. I think the test is doing what you want to achieve.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

main() {
  test(
      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769602/error-while-sorting-json-array-using-flutter',
      () {
    var jsonString = '''{"unit": [
        {
            "unit_id": "268",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "13",
            "unit_name": "File Handling and Dictionaries",
            "unit_no": "6"
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "274",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "24",
            "unit_name": "Object Oriented Programming",
            "unit_no": "5"
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "300",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "14",
            "unit_name": "Decision Control Statements",
            "unit_no": "2"
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "304",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "29",
            "unit_name": "Problem Solving, Programming and Python Programming",
            "unit_no": "1"
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "392",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "11",
            "unit_name": "Functions & Modules",
            "unit_no": "3"
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "393",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "53",
            "no_chapters": "28",
            "unit_name": "Strings",
            "unit_no": "4"
        },
        {
            "unit_id": "298",
            "univ_spec_sub_id": "59",
            "no_chapters": "16",
            "unit_name": "Electromagnetism",
            "unit_no": "1"
        }
]}''';

    var extractdata = json.decode(jsonString);
    List unitdata = extractdata["unit"];
    //unitdata.forEach((item) => print(item));
    unitdata.sort((a, b) {
      final specSubIdComparison =
          a['univ_spec_sub_id'].compareTo(b['univ_spec_sub_id']);
      if (specSubIdComparison != 0) {
        return specSubIdComparison;
      } else {
        return a["unit_no"].compareTo(b["unit_no"]);
      }
    });

    unitdata.forEach((item) => print(item));
    //return Semdata.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

    expect(unitdata[0]['univ_spec_sub_id'], '53');
    expect(unitdata[0]['unit_no'], '1');
    expect(unitdata[1]['univ_spec_sub_id'], '53');
    expect(unitdata[1]['unit_no'], '2');
    expect(unitdata[2]['univ_spec_sub_id'], '53');
    expect(unitdata[2]['unit_no'], '3');
    expect(unitdata[3]['univ_spec_sub_id'], '53');
    expect(unitdata[3]['unit_no'], '4');
    expect(unitdata[4]['univ_spec_sub_id'], '53');
    expect(unitdata[4]['unit_no'], '5');
    expect(unitdata[5]['univ_spec_sub_id'], '53');
    expect(unitdata[5]['unit_no'], '6');
    expect(unitdata[6]['univ_spec_sub_id'], '59');
    expect(unitdata[6]['unit_no'], '1');
  });
}
```

Comment: Great !! Thanks for the help